# How could I passthrough dynamic JSON fields in ksqlDB

Tags: ksqldb

I have a stream of events in Kafka that I would like to enrich with some more data based on a calculation in ksqlDB v0.29.0.

The JSON message is quite large so for simplicity let's assume the message has the following format:

```
{
    "messageid": "c1fb23bf-9b98-48d4-88d6-db6b0cbde999",
    "timestamp": "2023-07-12T08:35:23.2345Z",
    "data": {
        "event": "A event just happend",
        "state": "down",
        "tags": [],
        "metadata": {
            "fied1": "value 1",
            "dynamicfield1": {
                "somefield1": "somevalue 1"
            },
            "dynamicfield2": [
                {
                    "somefield2": "somevalue 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The two dynamic fields, dynamicfield1 and dynamicfield2, are generated by a legacy system that cannot be changed. These field can either be a JSON object or a JSON array.

I've created a table from the topic and can calculate my tags fine, but I need to update the source topic with these tags but keep the rest of the messages the same.

Initially I thought I could just define the two dynamic fields as VARCHAR in my table definition but that generated an escaped JSON string that the downstream system can't handle. Then I thought I could use the following functions:

[JSON_ITEMS](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#json_items) and [JSON_RECORDS](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#json_records) with COALESCE but then I get a type-cast error from COALESCE because JSON_ITEMS returns an ARRAY and JSON_RECORDS returns a MAP.

I've also tried to change the column definition for these fields to be of type BYTES but this fails to deserialize.

How could I keep these two dynamic fields valid JSON without them being escaped JSON strings?